# How to get value between 2 different characters

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a string that varies in length. The values for example are:

```
\\gogbg\statements\invoices\2020\02\02\343554.csv
\\gogbg\statements\invoices\2019\02\04\90654324.csv
```

I need the value before `.` and after `\` such as `343554` and `90654324`.

Using SQL Server - how do I retrieve these values?

Answer (score 4):

You can try something like this (which you could put into a scalar-valued function, for instance):

```
DECLARE @Input VARCHAR(100) = '\\gogbg\statements\invoices\2020\02\02\343554.csv';

-- get the reversed string
DECLARE @Reversed VARCHAR(100) = REVERSE(@Input);

-- get the position of the dot '.' and the first backslash in the reversed string
SET @DotPos = CHARINDEX('.', @Reversed);
SET @BackslashPos = CHARINDEX('\', @Reversed);

-- extract characters between those to positions, and then reverse back
SET @Result = REVERSE (SUBSTRING(@Reversed, @DotPos, @BackslashPos - @DotPos));
```

This would return the desired value - `343554`

Comment: @AutumnSunflower: If you feel this answer helped you solve your problem, then please [**accept this answer**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/5234/153998). This will show your appreciation for the people who *spent their own time to help you*.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably, you have the value in a column.  If the string always ends in ".csv", then a simple approach is:

```
select t.*,
       replace(right(t.str, charindex('\', reverse(t.str)) - 1), '.csv', '')
from (values ('\\gogbg\statements\invoices\2020\02\02\343554.csv'),
             ('\\gogbg\statements\invoices\2019\02\04\90654324.csv')
     ) t(str) ;
```

For a variable suffix, you can use:

```
select t.*,
       left(v.ending, charindex('.', v.ending) - 1)
from (values ('\\gogbg\statements\invoices\2020\02\02\343554.csv'),
             ('\\gogbg\statements\invoices\2019\02\04\90654324.csv')
     ) t(str) cross apply
     (values (right(t.str, charindex('\', reverse(t.str)) - 1))) v(ending);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6af1c77f8622b7ac3db6fc42f5499080) is a db<>fiddle.